I can't align items center of page
I want to align items center of page. I use justifyContent on all css styles but it doesn't work. I want to align them dynamically. I don't want to use marginTop:xxx. I want to align all items when i add a new category or new categories to application. I want to align them with alignItems, justifyContent etc.

const CategoriesScreen = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<ICategories>()
  const navigation:any = useNavigation();
  const [select, setSelected] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() =>{
  fetchCategories();

  },[])

  const fetchCategories = async () =>{
    try {
      setCategories((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        pending:false,
        errorMsg:""
      }));
      const categories = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories');
      const categoriesJson = await categories.json();

      setCategories((prevState) =>({
        ...prevState,
        categories : categoriesJson,
        pending:false,
        errorMsg:""
   
      }));


    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error :", err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <FlatList
        data={categories?.categories}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
        <Pressable 
        onPress={() => alert("deneme")}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          { backgroundColor: pressed ? 'red' : 'transparent' },
          styles.categoriesStyle
          
      ]} 
          >
          <Text >{item}</Text>
        </Pressable>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
        />
  
    </View>
  )
}

export default CategoriesScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:"white",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center"
  },

  categoriesStyle:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:"lightgray",
    margin:"5%",
    textAlign:"center",
    borderRadius:20,
    width: 300,
    padding:"10%",
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center"
  }
}) 

I tried justifyContent and alignItems but they didn't work.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please provide more details as in which component you want to be centered and please provide details of the parent component as well. After this I will be able to help you

@Paulie_D Thanks for your answer. I'm new at here so I don't know how can i ask questions without mistakes :) Thanks for your suggestion.

@BasitMir I want to align flatlist items. It may be 4 clickable item and they must be center of page. For now, it is a main component and first page of my app.

First try wrapping your pressable around a View and give the center styling to it. If it doesn't work. You can also experiment using  instead of . Let me know if works

@ErenAvar I got it ! , Please use a prop in FlatList called "contentContainerStyle" and then give the center styles to this. This will most likely work

You've to added a contentContainerStyle prop of the FlatList component. This style ensures that the content of the FlatList is centered both horizontally and vertically within its container.
Like this:-


const CategoriesScreen = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<ICategories>();
  const navigation: any = useNavigation();
  const [select, setSelected] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);

  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    try {
      setCategories((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        pending: false,
        errorMsg: "",
      }));
      const categories = await fetch(
        'https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories'
      );
      const categoriesJson = await categories.json();

      setCategories((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        categories: categoriesJson,
        pending: false,
        errorMsg: "",
      }));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error :", err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={categories?.categories}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => alert("deneme")}
            style={({ pressed }) => [
              { backgroundColor: pressed ? "red" : "transparent" },
              styles.categoriesStyle,
            ]}
          >
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CategoriesScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  listContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  categoriesStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    margin: "5%",
    textAlign: "center",
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: 300,
    padding: "10%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});



